# Change Chrome 'No Internet connection' screen

Tags: google-chrome, browser

Is there any way how to change Chrome's 'No Internet connection' screen (the one with the T-Rex)? 
Can this be done with other browsers?

Comment: Does this have anything to do with programming? This just seems like a Chrome question.

Comment: Which would be the right stackexchange for that? Because I actually would like to do it programmatically

Comment: If you have a *specific* question regarding how to do it programmatically, it's on topic here. This question as is is far too broad as it is though. Really, you should have already gotten a start on it before posting here. If you need help starting out, I don't think there's a SE site where this is ontopic. Try Reddit or Google+.

Comment: As I couldn't find out if it is even possible I thought this would be the right place to ask beforehand. Thanks for your information!